# On mouse over on a link i want to change background color of div and link

Tags: html, css

I have  a div

```
<div id="box">
content content
content content <a href="#">content</a>content
</div>
```

On mouse over on the link i want to change the color of the link and also the background color of the div.  Using only css,   Is it possible only using css?
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no CSS selector for target `parent` element. But can achieve the desire effect with some tricks. write like this:

```
#box a:hover:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:red;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/V4qDm/3/

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/V4qDm/2/

**Add this CSS**

```
#box.hover{background:#cb2326;}
#box a{display:inline-block;}
#box a:hover{color:#fff;}
```

**Add this Jquery:**

```
​$('a').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
});​​​
```

Comment: That's only part of the solution: "..and also the background color of the div" Hence the -1

Comment: Now check the working fiddle it will surely solve your problem. Only css is solution is possible only with css4. So its good to use Jquery if u really want to to get the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the link color using

```
   a:hover{color:#ccc;}
```

but you can't access parent element from children using css3 or css 2.

It has been provided in css4 with $sign

```
$div>a:hover{background:#ccc;}
```

but currently no browser support it

You have to look into javascript to change the parent background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:hover` on the div, it is supported in all browsers apart from IE6, which has very few* users today:

```
div#box:hover {
background-color: #whatever;
}
```

**Edit:** Of course I completely misunderstood the question. Apologies! As others have pointed out it is not possible for a child element to alter its parent's appearance in CSS (well, at least until CSS4). If it's acceptable for the parent to act as trigger then the above works, and you can of course alter the appearance of the link at the same time:

```
div#box:hover a {
color: #somecolour;
}
```

*) 0.66% according to [statcounter.com](http://www.statcounter.com)

Comment: While I would never advocate a method which prevents users of *any* browser from accessing your website, a missing :hover effect will (should) not have any major effect on usability.

Comment: -1,He want to change `#box` color of div on hovering over link not itself

Comment: Oh. My bad. I think I need to take more time to actually read the questions before replying...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using javascript, it makes simple tasks as this exactly what they are; simple!

Add the following in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDivAndLink(linkid, divid){
        document.getElementById(linkid).setColor(...);
        document.getElementById(divid).setBackground(...);
    }
</script>
```

Then, all you need to do to your code is add the onmouseover:

```
<div id="box">
    content content
    content content <a href="#">content</a>content
</div>
```

I know you actually wanted to do it without the use of scripting, but javascript is so widely supported these days, that the percentage of browsers not supporting it is negliable.

Hope this helped some.

Answer (score 0):

To make the whole div act as a link, set the anchor tag as: `display: block;`
Then set your height of the anchor tag to 100%. set div tag height to fixed size.

example:

```
    <html>
<head>
        <title>sample link</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        .container {
                border: 1px solid #C9F;
                width: 50%;
                height: 20px;
        }

        .container a {
                display: block;
                background: #FC6;
                height: 100%;
                text-align: center;
        }

        .container a:hover {
                background: #996699;
                color:#FFF;
        }

        </style>

</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
                <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
        </div>


</body>
 </html>
```